# Help with Matrix->Playa->Matrix while using Stash for {image_1} shortcode replacements

Tags: matrix, playa, stash, shortcode

No, it's actually not as convoluted as it sounds... ;)

Got two channels: News, and News Commentary. News entries are published multiple times per day; News Commentary is published once a week and covers 5-10 News entries from that week.

News has a `news__body` field, a `news__images` Matrix of images (containing the usual suspect columns of `file`, `caption`, etc), and a `news__credits` Matrix field with some plain text columns. It uses image shortcodes (those `{image_1}` / `{image_2}` things) in the `news__body` field to insert images from the `news__images` field.

News Commentary basically just has a `commentary__content` Matrix field, which has a `related-news-article` Playa column linking each row to a News entry, as well as a `commentary` textarea for the commentary portion.

The single-entry page for News Commentary displays a list (the `commentary__content` matrix). Each list item should display the related News entry's `news__body` and `news__credits` fields (with images in position), with the commentary following.

I've got much of it working, but seem **unable to get output from the News Commentary -> related News entry -> `news__images` or `news__credits` field.** I get the `news__body` content with `{image_1}` shortcodes showing in the text, followed by the `commentary` content - no `news__credits` or replaced image shortcodes.

Following is my (simplified) template. It contains both the `{exp:stash:set_list}` and `{exp:stash:get_list}` loops.

Stash set_list:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="news-commentary" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news-commentary" require_entry="yes"}
        {stash:commentary__title}{title}{/stash:commentary__title}
        {stash:news-commentary__entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:news-commentary__entry_id}
        {exp:stash:set_list:commentary__content name="commentary__content" context="entry_{entry_id}"     parse_tags="yes"}
            {commentary__content} {!-- Matrix --}
                {stash:row_count}{row_count}{/stash:row_count}
                {related-news-article var_prefix="related_article"} {!-- Playa --}

                    {stash:news__title}{related_article:title}{/stash:news__title}
                    {stash:news__entry_id}{related_article:entry_id}{/stash:news__entry_id}

                    {related_article:news__images var_prefix="image_matrix"} {!-- Matrix --}
                        {exp:stash:set name="image_{image_matrix:row_count}" type="snippet"}
                            <img src="{image_matrix:file}">
                        {/exp:stash:set}
                    {/related_article:news__images} {!-- END Matrix --}

                    {!-- Parse to replace image shortcodes with images - theoretically --}
                    {exp:stash:parse parse_vars="yes" process="end"}
                        {stash:news__body}{related_article:news__body}{/stash:news__body}
                    {/exp:stash:parse}

                    {exp:stash:set_list:news__credits name="news__credits" context="entry_{entry_id}" parse_tags="yes"}
                        {related_article:news-credits var_prefix="credits_matrix"}
                            {stash:credits__text}{credits_matrix:text}{/stash:credits__text}
                            {stash:credits__url}{credits_matrix:url}{/stash:credits__url}
                        {/related_article:news-credits}
                    {/exp:stash:set_list:credits}

                {/related-news-article} {!-- END Playa --}
                {stash:commentary}{commentary}{/stash:commentary}
            {/commentary__content} {!-- END Matrix --}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:commentary__content}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Stash get_list:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="news-commentary"}
    <h1>{commentary__title}</h1>
    <ol class="commentary-list">
    {exp:stash:get_list:commentary__content name="commentary__content" context="entry_{news-commentary__entry_id}"}
        <li>
            <h2>{news__title}</h2>
            {news__body}

            {exp:stash:get_list:news__credits name="news__credits" context="entry_{news__entry_id}"}
                    {stash:credits__text}
                    {stash:credits__url}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:credits}

            {if commentary}
                <h3>Commentary</h3>
                {commentary}
            {/if}
        </li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:commentary__content}
    </ol>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

FYI, due to massive simplification and obfuscation of the actual template code, any typos you find may or may not be actual problems in the original template. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Without digging too much into your code, I think the problem is you need to parse tags on the `get_list` not the `set_list` (or possibly both).

The `news__body` field will need to be parsed again by the template parser for the shortcodes to render as snippets are parsed really early.

So update

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="news-commentary"}...
```

To become:

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="news-commentary" parse_tags="yes"}
```

Hopefully that will get it working for you.